# Azure Pipeline fails on npm run build, missing vueapp.key file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, azure-devops

I'm having problems with building Vue app in azure pipelines, I do not have experience with NodeJS or Vue, and I'm not sure what is is looking for. Locally my application builds and runs without any problem. Any help would be appreciated. I think it has to do with the vue.config.js file setup, but I'm not sure how to configure it for it to work during build in Azure and be production ready.

```
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
9.8.1
/usr/local/bin/npm config list
; "env" config from environment

userconfig = "/home/vsts/work/1/npm/70.npmrc" 

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; node version = v18.18.2
; npm local prefix = /home/vsts/work/1/s/testapp1/Prototype.Vue/vueapp
; npm version = 9.8.1
; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/testapp1/Prototype.Vue/vueapp
; HOME = /home/vsts
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
/usr/local/bin/npm run build

> vueapp@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build

 ERROR  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/.aspnet/https/vueapp.key'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/.aspnet/https/vueapp.key'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:603:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:471:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vsts/work/1/s/testapp1/Prototype.Vue/vueapp/vue.config.js:23:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at exports.loadModule (/home/vsts/work/1/s/testapp1/Prototype.Vue/vueapp/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/module.js:86:14)
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: npm build
```

here is my current vue.config.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const baseFolder =
    process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : "vueapp";

if (!certificateName) {
    console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
    process.exit(-1);
}

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        },
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7020/'
            } 
        },
        port: 5002
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @matendie, Thx for the sharing. Would you consider accepting your answer? That may help others with similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my default configuration to include production in thy way:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Function to read SSL certificate in development
function getSSLCertificate() {
    const baseFolder = process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

    const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
    const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : "vueapp";

    if (!certificateName) {
        console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
        process.exit(-1);
    }

    const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
    const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

    return {
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath)
    };
}

// Common configuration options (used in both development and production)
const commonConfig = {
    // common settings
};

// Development specific configuration
const devConfig = {
    devServer: {
        https: getSSLCertificate(),
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7020/'
            } 
        },
        port: 5002
    }
};

// Production specific configuration
const prodConfig = {
    // Production settings, e.g., different publicPath, plugins, etc.
};

module.exports = {
    ...commonConfig,
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodConfig : devConfig)
};
```